# Use vs 2013 templates in vs 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-templates

I'd like to follow along with the tutorials on the second half of this page. http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-aspnet-identity

It looks like they're using vs 2013 templates. I am currently using vs 2012.  Can I download and use these templates vs 2012?